# UI Unresposive issue on parallel.for loop

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

Im building a notepad application on c# with the use of the task parallel library but when apply I apply the search function the whole UI gets stuck. I tried invoking the  method but still it wasnt helpful. The following is the search function.

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Parallel.For(0, GetRichTextBox().Text.LastIndexOf(toolStripTextBox1.Text) + 1, (int i) =>
        {
            GetRichTextBox().Find(toolStripTextBox1.Text, i, GetRichTextBox().TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            GetRichTextBox().SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange;
            i = GetRichTextBox().Text.IndexOf(toolStripTextBox1.Text, i) + 1;
        });
    }
```

The following code is the GetRichTextBox method.

```
 public  RichTextBox GetRichTextBox()
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
        TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
        if(tp!= null)
        {
            rtb = tp.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
        }

        }));
        return rtb;
    }
```

Comment: Parallel.For itself does not run in another thread. Also, attempting to do UI work in the background almost always involves calling `Invoke` which runs on the UI thread so performance wise there is nothing to gain.

Comment: I know but it’s a requirement for my assignment :/

Answer (score 0):

The code: `GetRichTextBox()` gets invoked on the UI thread (by the use of the `Invoke(...)` method).

In the body of your parallel for loop, you call that method 4 times. Thus most of the parallel body is invoked on the UI thread, thus making your application unresponsive.

---

### Sort of fix:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private void toolStripButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the textbox just once.
    var textBox = GetRichTextBox();
    // Set the selection color also just once.
    textBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange;

    // get the text to find
    var textToFind = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
    // get the text to search in
    var completeText = textBox.Text;

    // escape the text to find because we are using regex to find them
    var escapedTextToFind = Regex.Escape(textToFind);
    // find all the index of the search text int the complete text
    var indexes = Regex.Matches(completeText, escapedTextToFind)
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Index);

    // select every found index in the textbox
    foreach (var selectionStartIndex in indexes)
    {
        textBox.Select(selectionStartIndex, textToFind.Length);
    }
}

// No needs for invoke, since we want to do UI stuff on the UI thread
public RichTextBox GetRichTextBox()
{
    // instead of null checks, you can use the null conditional operators
    // see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators
    return tabControl1?.SelectedTab?.Controls?[0] as RichTextBox;
}
```

I doubt this would work, because I believe you can select multiple texts at the same time. Because most of this code does stuff on the UI, you should do all of it on the UI. But if the text amount is very large, and the UI still hangs, you could the bold part in parallel. But I think it is overkill.

Comment: What’s the solution I have for this problem? Sorry I’m fairly new to programming.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that you wish to make a selection in the `GetRichTextBox()`, and the text that needs to be select should be `toolStripTextBox1.Text` ?